# When using mod_rewrite, calling my webpage with a slash at the end causes issues with ajax calls

Tags: php, ajax, mod-rewrite

Using PHP, rewrite rules, and javascript(ajax). I am having major issues with my page not working when adding a slash at the end.

When I call my webpage as `www.website.com/example` everything works fine.
When I call my webpage as `www.website.com/example/` or `www.website.com/example/param`everything is slow and eventually my web browser will crash.

I have narrowed it down to specific parts of my javascript where I use ajax to call another php file to replace the inner html of a div. I replaced that with an alert to see what it was returning, and it was returning my entire webpage, including the  that was calling my js again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you add a leading slash to your urls, it works fine.

`url:  'somefile.php',`

to

`url:  '/somefile.php',`